# SQL via ODBC FileMaker fields separated by a ¶?

Tags: sql, odbc, filemaker

I've run into a bit of a problem, I'm querying a filemaker database via ODBC from Python and I'm having an issue with fields that contain multiple values.

for example, in filemaker the field shows:

'5.2976e+17'

but when i click into it it shows the data I need:

529763

576932

516528

problem is SQL brings back the first example. And this causes a problem when I'm trying to search for these number I'm not getting a match.

When the numbers have been added to the field they have been added with a ¶ at the end of each line.

The Field is set as 'Number' and options are 'Indexed'

Any ideas why it's doing this?

Thanks!

Richard

Answer (score 0):

On the layout you are using for ODBC, select the fields in question and change the data formatting options in the Inspector to ‘As entered’

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that your field is set as FileMaker data type "number". Change it into data type "text" in the field preferences